# Html.TextBoxFor showing Empty Value but the model is not empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi all I'm having trouble correctly display the data in the textbox
This is my Print partialView

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@model Estudio.WebUI.Models.PrintViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Print", new { @class = "openDialog data-dialog-id='PrintDialog' data-dialog-Title='Print'" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "PrintDialog" }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FacturaId)
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NComprobante)
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NComprobante)
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SendMail)
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SendMail)
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="Imprimir" value="Imprimir" id="Imprimir"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#NComprobante").mask("99999-999999999999");
    });
</script>    
}
```

This is ActionResult Print

```
   public ActionResult Print(string id)
    {
        ...
        var model = new PrintViewModel
                        {
                            FacturaId = factura.FacturaId,
                            NComprobante = numero[0] + "-" + comprabante.ToString("000000000000")
                        };
        return PartialView("Print", model);
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the mask JavaScript function doing?

Comment: What happens if you comment out `$("#NComprobante").mask("99999-999999999999");`?

Comment: yes my model was wrong.It was a silly question, but after trying many things I could not fix it.

Comment: when comment $("#NComprobante").mask("99999-999999999999"); then detect missing characters in the property NComprobante

Comment: Es numero[0] null?  Cuando uno concatena los strings junto y uno es "null" el resultado es null tambien.

Comment: No el error estaba aquí comprabante.ToString("000000000000")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong code on

```
NComprobante = numero[0] + "-" + comprabante.ToString("000000000000")
```

the correct is:

```
var comprabante = numero[0] + "-" + (Convert.ToDouble(numero[1]) + 1).ToString("0000000000000");
```